# Why docker desktop on windows 10 Home don't have ADVANCED option in Resources tab

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I've followed the docs to use docker with WSL 2 and installed the Ubuntu 18.04 for WSL 2.
My sys_version is win10_home_19042.867.
I puzzled that  "From the Windows Start menu, Settings > Resources > " BUT don't have 'ADVANCED' options,which helps to configure CPU, memory, disk, proxies, network, and other resources.
[image: my settings tab]
I've noitice that "The Advanced tab is only available in Hyper-V mode". Is there any other way to get over it?
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is not part of Windows 10 Home (you need Professional to be able to enable it) and those Docker Desktop advanced settings are only relevant to Hyper-V.

When running in WSL2 mode those limits (CPU, memory) need to be done via `.wslconfig` file - see [here](https://itnext.io/wsl2-tips-limit-cpu-memory-when-using-docker-c022535faf6f?gi=43d7a868712e).